# Which Naruto episode shows a flashback of a kid stealing bread?

Tags: naruto

I am trying to remember a scene in *Naruto* where a "homeless kid" steals bread and gets beaten up and Orochimaru or someone comes and ask him to follow him.

Which episode is this from?

Answer (score 3):

That boy was [Zaku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Zaku_Abumi). The flashback is shown during his fight against Shino in episode [40](http://www.animefamily.com/Naruto/Nar/Nar40.htm).

Comment: @Raingod mark this as the answer then.